# Get ng-repeat data to appear in 4 columns

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, checklist-model

I'm getting list of data from Db to a view using ng-repeat. In order to select multiple values at once I'm using checklist-model. My code is as follows,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type=checkbox checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="item"/>{{item}}
</div>
```

This will return a long list one below another. What I need is to get these data in the list to be displayed in 4 columns. Any help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQZH0HOxTFpoytPPbfSR?p=preview)

This is what you are looking for. Hope that solve your problem.

```
 <div ng-repeat="product in products" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"> <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="{{products[$index]}}"/>{{products[$index]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"> <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="{{products[$index]}}"/>{{products[$index+1]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"> <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="{{products[$index]}}"/>{{products[$index+2]}}</div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Still this will return values in a single column. I want the data in 4 columns divided equally. What this does is add the values to a row

Comment: @TharinduSenanayake What do you mean by single column? [Check this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WNxztaH1YWv77qL4lbz3?p=preview). I have added table border. It displays data in three separate columns. Similar output can be rendered by `div`.

Comment: Yes tried adding another 3 values to the scope object. Then it returned 6 values in 6 columns. What I want is the additional 3 values to be added to the first 3 columns under first 3 values respectively

Comment: @TharinduSenanayake edited answer. Hope that solve your problem.

Comment: I used this before. But when I use checklist-model, this does not work. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Can you add any plnkr/fiddle? It is difficult to assume your problem.

Comment: @TharinduSenanayake Edited my answer. I don't see any problem after adding `checklist-model`.

Comment: Thank you so much @KhalidHussain you made my day

Answer (score 0):

You could use display:inline-block on your elements that you want in a row. How you lay them out within that row could be done different ways depending on what you are seeking.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" style="display:inline-block;">
  <input type=checkbox checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="item"/>{{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: The issue Im having is not getting the data into a row. I want the data divided into 4 columns. I have about 1000 data values. I want them in 4 columns with 200 data in each column

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment. It looks like you want to traverse horizontally, so you can use $index and modulo (% 4) to see if you are at the end of a row and ng-if a <br/>.

If it were me, I would use CSS and not use JS for something that is not hard to do in CSS with nth-of-type or something similar.